# Sending contents of a data extension to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a Data Extension for product catalogues downloaded done by one lead. How can we sync that information to sales cloud? We'd like to create a campaign for each download associated to the lead record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Server-Side JavaScript](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/). You would first have to [Retrieve](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/retrieve/) the contents and pass the array to a  to make a [POS](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/http_server_side_javascript_functions/post/)T call to the Salesforce Update Object API